# PHP DateTime with TimeZone to MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime

Tags: php, mongodb, datetime, bson

I need help with PHP DateTime with TimeZone converting to MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime. 
If I have string "**2015-10-20T04:02:00.608000+01:00**" it gives me a DateTime

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uT', $string );

DateTime
date => "2015-10-20 04:02:00.608000"
timezone_type => 1
timezone => "+01:00"
```

If I convert it to MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime and convert back to PHP DateTime

```
$mDate = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime( $date->format('U') * 1000 );
$mDate->toDateTime()->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Bratislava'))
```

I will get a correct result **05:02**

```
DateTime
date => "2015-10-20 05:02:00.000000"
timezone_type => 3
timezone => "Europe/Bratislava"
```

BUT if the input string has **+02:00** TimeZone "**2015-10-20T04:02:00.608000+02:00**" and use the same approach the result is

```
DateTime
date => "2015-10-20 04:02:00.000000"
timezone_type => 3
timezone => "Europe/Bratislava"
```

Why is the second result 04:02 if I expect **06:02**?

Comment: Could you show us how you are creating your first PHP DateTime?

Comment: The question was updated. There it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The response is correct. When you are adding a `+` timezone onto the timestamp, you are, in effect going East from UTC. You are not *adding* to the UTC time, you are actually *subtracting* from what the time is in UTC. This means that `2015-10-20T04:02:00.608000+01:00` is 3am UTC. `2015-10-20T04:02:00.608000+02:00` is 2am UTC. You can see this more easily if you keep going higher with your timezone offsets

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uT', "2015-10-20T04:02:00.608000+01:00");
$mDate = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime( $date->format('U') * 1000 );
var_dump($date, $mDate->toDateTime());

object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-10-20 04:02:00.608000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+01:00"
}
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-10-20 03:02:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}


$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uT', "2015-10-20T04:02:00.608000+02:00");
$mDate = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime( $date->format('U') * 1000 );
var_dump($date, $mDate->toDateTime());

object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-10-20 04:02:00.608000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+02:00"
}
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-10-20 02:02:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
```

MongoDB stores the UTC timestamp. When you are adding the `Europe/Bratislava` timezone, you are saying, "What time is in Bratislava for this UTC timestamp". For October (daylight savings time), it's a 1 hr difference.

On a side note. Try to ***never*** mix `+XXXX` and Unicode/Olson timezones (`Europe/Bratislava`). You will wind up with some very strange errors due to daylight savings time. If you need to record a user's local time to display back at some point, Create your `DateTime` objects with the optional 3rd parameter like:

```
$customerTz = 'Europe/Bratislava';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u', $dateString, $customerTz);
```

Also check to see if you really need to create a `DateTime` at all, or just a new `UTCDateTime` directly with a timestamp and deal with the tz's in the display logic.

Comment: Thank you so much. So you say all that results I have in my question are correct? I was little confused because of 2015-10-20T04:02:00.608000+01:00 where +01:00 is incorrect because of daylight of this date is +02:00. I added +01:00 manually for test reasons. So php engine correctly adds +02:00 hours and makes time 05:02. Am I right?